# $f'$ changes strict monotonicity but $f''$ isn't of strictly opposite signs

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and $f \in C^2(I,\mathbb{R})$.

I am looking for an (simple) example of $f$ with the following properties ($x_0 \in I$)

$f'$ is strictly monotonic increasing for $x < x_0$ and strictly monotonic decreasing for $x > x_0$.

However the following property must be violated on every neighborhood of $x_0$: $f''(x) > 0$ for $x < x_0$ and $f''(x) < 0$ for $x > x_0$.

The background for this question is studying points of inflection i.e. $(x_0,f(x_0))$ satisfying the first property above (or increasing/decreasing swapped) on a neighborhood of $x_0$. Now if there is a neighborhood $U \subset I$ of $x_0$ where $f''(x) < 0$ for $x < x_0$ and $f''(x) > 0$ for $x > x_0$ (or the other way around), the point $(x_0,f(x_0))$ is a point of inflection. The intention of my question was to find an (simple) example which shows that the reversed implication is wrong.

Comment: Why do you need $f$ -- can't you phrase the  question directly with $g,g^{\prime}$, where $g=f^\prime$ and $g^\prime=f^{\prime\prime}$?

Comment: @ClementC. Ideally I want a simple example where one can "write down" a term for $f$ and not only saying that there exists some (maybe very complicated) primitive of your $g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
g(x)=-\int_{x_0}^xt\sin^2\frac1t\,dt.
$$
Then $g$ is strictly decreasing on $x>x_0$ and strictly increasing on $x<x_0$, but $g'$ has zeroes on any neighborhood of $x_0$. Now define
$$
f(x)=\int_{x_0}^xg(t)\,dt.
$$

Answer (score 1):

How about
$$ f(x) = \int_0^x (1-t^2)^3\,dt $$
This gives $f'(x) = (1-x^2)^3$ which satisfies the monotonicity requirement.

But $f''(-1)=f''(1)=0$.

---

If you want $f''(x)=0$ arbitrarily close to $x_0$, that can be arranged too: Let
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when }x=0 \\
    \dfrac{1}{1/x+\sin(1/x)} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
and then
$$ f(x) = \int_0^x g(-t^2)\,dt $$

The point here is that $g$ is strictly increasing and differentiable everywhere with $g'(0)=1$, but $g'(x)=0$ whenever $x$ is the reciprocal of an odd multiple of $\pi$ -- that is, arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: Thanks, but I noticed that I wasn't precise enough. I want that the property with the second derivative is violated on every neighborhood of $x_0$. See my edit.

Comment: @Julia: New example achieves that.

Answer (score 1):

> **Edit:** The Question has in effect been modified to require $f''(x)$ to have isolated zeros in any neighborhood of $x_0$, both above and below $x_0$, thus invalidating my answer (and those of other responders).  Since analytic functions cannot have zeros that "accumulate", a "natural" example becomes less tractable.  Probably the easiest approach would amount to defining $f$ "piecewise" on subintervals $[(n+1)^{-1},n^{-1}]$ and $[-n^{-1},-(n+1)^{-1}]$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ in a way that makes the second derivative continuous with zeros at each $\pm 1/n$.

If a "natural" example is wanted, we can start with the nonnegative even function:

$$ f'(x) = | x - \sin x | $$

which is strictly decreasing when $x \lt 0$ and strictly increasing when $x \gt 0$.  Moreover the function $f'(x)$ is differentiable (even at $x=0$ by symmetry), and its derivative is the odd function:

$$ f''(x) = (1 - \cos x)\cdot \text{signum}(x) $$

An indefinite integral of $f'$ is thus the odd function:

$$ f(x) = \left(\frac{x^2}{2} - 1 + \cos x \right)\cdot \text{signum}(x) $$

We avoid $f''(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \gt 0$ (resp. avoid $f''(x) \lt 0$ for all $x \lt 0$) because $f''(2k\pi) = 0$ for all integers $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks, but I noticed that I wasn't precise enough. I want that the property with the second derivative is violated on every neighborhood of $x_0$. See my edit.

Comment: @Julia: Certainly the zeros of my example $f''(x)$ do not accumulate at $x=0$.  I make it a policy not to pursue moving goal posts. I recommend you understand the principle in responses to your initial wording.  Make changes to have accumulating (but isolated) zeros of $f''(x)$ at $x_0$ if you see fit.